# Naive Bayes classifier not working for sentiment analysis

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I am trying to train a Naive Bayes classifier to predict whether a movie review is good or bad. 
I am following this tutorial but have run into an error when trying to train the model:

https://medium.com/@MarynaL/analyzing-movie-review-data-with-natural-language-processing-7c5cba6ed922

I have followed all steps until training the model. My data and code looks as such:

```
                                                 Reviews  Labels
0      For fans of Chris Farley, this is probably his...       1
1      Fantastic, Madonna at her finest, the film is ...       1
2      From a perspective that it is possible to make...       1
3      What is often neglected about Harold Lloyd is ...       1
4      You'll either love or hate movies such as this...       1
                                              ...     ...
14995  This is perhaps the worst movie I have ever se...       0
14996  I was so looking forward to seeing this film t...       0
14997  It pains me to see an awesome movie turn into ...       0
14998  "Grande Ecole" is not an artful exploration of...       0
14999  I felt like I was watching an example of how n...       0

gnb = MultinomialNB()
gnb.fit(all_train_set['Reviews'], all_train_set['Labels'])
```

However when trying to fit the model I receive this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'For fans of Chris Farley, this is probably his best film. David Spade pl
```

If anyone could help me decide why following this tutorial has gone wrong it would e greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: It's a poorly written tutorial. The input for the classifier is supposed to be the features dataframe, not the raw data dataframe.

Comment: It did confuse me a lot, otherwise what was the point in processing anything

Answer (score 0):

Indeed with Scikit-learn you have to convert texts to numbers before calling a classifier. You can do so by using, for instance, the [`CountVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) or the [`TfidfVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer).

If you want to use the more modern word embeddings, you can use the [Zeugma](https://github.com/nkthiebaut/zeugma) package (install it with `pip install zeugma` in a terminal), e.g.

```
from zeugma.embeddings import EmbeddingTransformer

embedding = EmbeddingTransformer('glove')

X = embedding.transform(all_train_set['Reviews'])
y = all_train_set['Labels']

gnb = MultinomialNB()
gnb.fit(X, y)
```

I hope it helps!